# How to trigger event on model update

Tags: angular, observable

I  want to trigger event when i update any value in model from view.

I am trying to make use of observable as fallow.

```
export class requestsComponent implements OnInit {

    private filter: Observable<{
        name: string;
        phone: number;
        email: string;
        agent: string;
    }>;
    constructor( @Inject(BookSiteVisitService) private bookSiteVisitService: BookSiteVisitService) {

        this.filter = new Observable(observer => {
        });
        this.filter.subscribe(
            value => {
                console.log(value);
            },
            error => { console.log(error) },
            () => {
                console.log('conmplete');
            }
        );
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

I have filter object  which i want to observer If there is any update in filter I have up update function which handle ui accordingly

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter.name" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter.phone" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  [(ngModel)]="filter.email"  class="form-control"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter.agent" class="form-control"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let request of requests">
        <td>{{request.customerName}}</td>
        <td>{{request.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{request.email}}</td>
        <td>{{request.comment}}</td>
        <td>{{request.representativeName}}</td>
        <td>{{request.requestType}}</td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ngModelChange` event for this:

```
<td>
  <input type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="filter.name"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange()" <--------
    class="form-control">
</td>
```

Another option would be to leverage the `ngDoCheck` hook method and the `KeyValueDiffers` class. Here is a sample:

```
constructor(differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
  this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
}

ngDoCheck() {
  var changes = this.differ.diff(this.filter);
  if (changes) {
    changes.forEachChangedItem((elt) => {
      if (elt.key === 'name') {
        (...)
      }

      if (elt.key === 'phone' ) {      
        (...)
      }

      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DoCheck-class.html

Comment: What do you mean? At which level? Within the `filter` object?